Why can't typescript correctly infer the return type of the overloaded function?
Consider the following code:
interface AssetClass {
  msciReferenceCode: number;
}

interface AssetSector {
  msciReferenceCode: number;
}

interface AssetSubSector {
  msciReferenceCode: number
}

class TestClass {
  isSectorPartOfClass(sector: AssetSector, assetClass: AssetClass) {
    const [parentClassId, _sectorId] = this.getHierarchyForTaxonomy(sector);
    
    return parentClassId === assetClass.msciReferenceCode;
  }

  getHierarchyForTaxonomy(taxonomy: AssetClass): [classId: number];
  getHierarchyForTaxonomy(taxonomy: AssetSector): [classId: number, sectorId: number];
  getHierarchyForTaxonomy(taxonomy: AssetSubSector): [classId: number, sectorId: number, subsectorId: number];
  getHierarchyForTaxonomy(taxonomy: AssetSector | AssetSubSector | AssetClass): number[] {
    const reference = taxonomy.referenceCode;
    if (!reference) return [];

    return reference.toString().match(/.{2}/g)?.map(referenceString => parseInt(referenceString)) ?? [];
  }
}

Why can't typescript correctly infer the overload that is being used based on the input type provided to the function?
Here's a fiddle showing the error what I mean:
Fiddle

typescript structural typing, your 3 interfaces are considered equivalent.

It's because of structural typing, one of the most fundamental aspects of TypeScript; your three overloads all have the same parameters and so the first one is always selected. Does that fully address your question? If so someone will answer (or more likely, close this as a duplicate). If not, what are we missing?
